# README of a Maven package is not presented at AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, readme, aws-codeartifact

I wish to present a README file on CodeArtifact.  I deployed a new version that contains a `README.MD` file however the Description (marked in red) is greyed out.

Found [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/APIReference/API_GetPackageVersionReadme.html) however I did not understand what I should do to present my `README.MD` file.

- I can view the README at Bitbucket and inside the Intellij.
- Java code.
- Maven project management.

[image]

Following @Ermiya Eskandary comment, I made two README files, one in the root and a second in root of the module. After redeploying, the description is still not showing.

Project structure:

[image]

The POM file of the relevant module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>---</artifactId>
        <groupId>---</groupId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>---</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>---</groupId>
            <artifactId>---</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: What's the language of the package?

Comment: @baduker, my code is in Java. I thought that it isn't important.

Comment: What is the exact path for the readme file?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, Thanks, the readme is in the main directory.  Added project structure.

Comment: @Cohensius Try making the `MD` lowercase i.e. rename `README.MD` to `README.md`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, Thanks, tried it, does not help.

Comment: @Cohensius what’s inside your POM.xml file?

Comment: Also, how did you make your readme file? Does it have correct file permissions perhaps? Try creating & uploading a completely different readme and see if that works.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for trying to figure this problem.  Do you have any other ideas about what I can try?

Comment: @Cohensius Did uploading a different readme file work? Maybe try recreating the package? Can you reproduce this with a new Java artefact with the same readme? Or with a different readme?

Comment: a different readme file did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CodeArtifact does not currently support displaying Readme files for Maven packages. The GetPackageVersionReadme API will return "not found" for all Maven packages.

```
$ aws codeartifact get-package-version-readme \
>     --domain test \
>     --repo my-repo-name \
>     --format maven \
>     --package commons-lang \
>     --namespace commons-lang \
>     --package-version 2.1 \
>     --profile my_profile_name

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetPackageVersionReadme operation: The readme file of this package version is not found
```

Comment: Can you add a link to where it says this in the docs? Because they seem to suggest it's possible https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/APIReference/API_GetPackageVersionReadme.html#API_GetPackageVersionReadme_RequestSyntax

Comment: The docs are incorrect. I will follow up to get that fixed.

Comment: The documentation has been updated.

Comment: I suggest as you are actually affiliated with the API you clerify that in your answer, so the community knows it is from an authoritative source.